# How to have 1 mouseover event for 2 or more GMap Polygon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, polygon

What I mean is if I have 2 Polygon on a Google Maps, when I mouseover on one of the Polygons, I want both Polygon to change color for example. How can I achieve this? Can this be done with jQuery?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

what version of google maps are you using? if it's V3 i know of a V3Gmap-jquery plugin:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/a-google-maps-version-3-jquery-plugin/

that might probably help you